# decorating and accessing $rootScope method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have decorated $rootScope in the config of module with a fn `safeApply`.

```
$provide.decorator('$rootScope', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
        $delegate.safeApply = function(fn) {
           ...
         };
         return $delegate;
         }
]);
```

Is it ok to access it like

```
 $scope.$root.safeApply();
```

or do I need to inject `$rootScope` and then call it.

Can I add this method to the prototype of  `$rootScope` so it will inherit in all `$scope`? How to do this.

### Edit

with khanh's response below, I may add bit more info. safeApply is a method used to trigger a digest cycle manually. The idea of decorating the $rootScope is from here https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma . Please see it in the comment. So, it is not decorating a method, more adding a functionality which is accessible across (scope of directive, controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators should be used with services instead of scopes.

Decorator is a mechanism that allows use to **wrap** original service and performs cross-cutting concerns like: caching, logging,.. and **leave the service intact** to focus on its business without **being polluted** by these code.

I would implement the decorator like this. Let's say, we have a service defined in another module:

```
var lib = angular.module("lib",[]);
lib.service("util",function(){
     this.saveFile = function(file){
       console.log("save file:" + file);
     }
});
```

We need to use this service and decorate it with our code to do some logging without polluting the service with logging logic:

```
app.config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('util', function($delegate) {

    var originalSaveFile = $delegate.saveFile;

    $delegate.saveFile = function(file){
       console.log("before save file");
       originalSaveFile.apply(this,arguments);
       console.log("after save file");
    }

    return $delegate;
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/nr1pnuTwkJshzmFmBg1k?p=preview)

Decorator is inspired from [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

In your case, you could just add the function to $rootScope in module's run block and all scopes will inherit the function.

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.safeApply = function(fn){
      console.log("safeApply");
  };
});
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FBYHnAvgrWukYHqHrP9E?p=preview)

We could also use decorator to do something like this, but it feels like it's not the right way as the idea of decorators is to create **wrappers**:

```
$provide.decorator('$rootScope', function($delegate) {

    $delegate.safeApply = function(fn){
      console.log("safe apply");
    }
    return $delegate;
  });
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/AeOjEOr6N3M41oPqXXV9?p=preview)

Comment: thanks. please see my edits to explain the motivation. I in fact use your method to decorate $exceptionHandler. but in this case, it is more adding a function to all scope.

Comment: @bsr: if you want to add a function to all scopes, just add it to rootScope and all scopes will inherit that function.

Comment: thanks.. where/how to do it. I tried it in the base controller, but then directive scope doesn't see it. I thought it can be done at config.

Comment: @bsr: Please have a look at the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/FBYHnAvgrWukYHqHrP9E?p=preview

Comment: @bsr: I added more information in my answer. We could also utilize decorator to add a method to $rootScope

Comment: thanks, I was trying to see whether your first approach work for directive controller. it didn't for me, and trying to update your directive. I am not an expert, and the plnkr is not complete. has some errors. http://plnkr.co/edit/KTsKxw0pNv5U9GQzBekS?p=preview

Comment: @bsr: I don't have errors. I also updated the fiddle to call safeApply from directive: http://plnkr.co/edit/z4P8tOWq2r94rjbrmdUy?p=preview

Comment: @bsr: the reason the directive does not show up is you forgot to add `restrict:"E"` to allow using it as an element.

Comment: thanks.. it is working.. strange, will look into my local code. http://plnkr.co/edit/KTsKxw0pNv5U9GQzBekS?p=preview thanks for your patience and help. will accept.